# Cannot move images other than TIFF to another folder when running application as exe

Tags: java, file-handling

I am making an application for moving images from one folder to another but I am getting error when I try to move files with extension other than TIFF. The important thing is when I run this program through Eclipse or as JAR it works fine & moves any Image with any Extension but as EXE it gives error. The sample code is as below :

```
public class MovingFilesExample {
public static ArrayList<File> oDesiredFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
public static String[] oFileNameStarts;
public static File oInputFile = new File("D:/For_Sonal/NewOutput/456214538741259_LAND.BMP"), oDestDir = new File("D:/FILECONVERSIONS/OUTPUT/");
public static String strDesiredName;
public static Path oSourcePath, oDestPath;
public static PrintStream ps;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        File file = new File("Exception.log");
        ps = new PrintStream(file);

        if(oDestDir.mkdirs())
        {
            System.out.println("Directories made !!!");
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Directories not made !!!");
            System.out.println();
        }

        File oOutputFile = new File(oDestDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + oInputFile_1.getName());
        oDestPath = oOutputFile.toPath();

        System.out.println("Destination Path : " + oOutputFile.toPath());

        oSourcePath = oInputFile_1.toPath();

        if(new File(oSourcePath.toString()).exists())
        {
            //Files.copy(oSourcePath, oDestPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            Files.move(oSourcePath, oDestPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace(ps);
    }

    ps.close();

}
```

I get "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\For_Sonal\NewOutput\456214538741259_LAND.BMP -> D:\FILECONVERSIONS\OUTPUT\456214538741259_LAND.BMP" at

```
Files.move(oSourcePath, oDestPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

I am also creating one Log file as "Exception.log" at application path so that we can view the Exception that occurs. So can anyone suggest me what could be the reason behind this.

Comment: figure out what's causing the access denied. one or more of the parent/container directories? the file itself?

Comment: Thanks for commenting Marc. Well I am a newbie to Java world and the problem I am facing is files are accessible when I run app through Eclipse as well as application's executable JAR but not when I wrap it into an EXE using launch4j. So does that mean EXE does not have access to certain files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Java. That's simple OS (Windows in this case) security settings.
Double check under what ID you run your exe. Is it some service or application like IIS? Usually they have some settings which identify what ID to use.

Simple way to understand it - run another process from within your Java app and in this process run command WhoAmI.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I am making a Desktop Application which is not going to be installed into system and it's not a service like IIS, for moving files from one folder to two other folders as per project requirements. I am currently using the application under Standard User Account but I am going to run it under Admin Account to see if it works then.

Comment: Well it happens to be that the Antivirus Policies were blocking my EXE to access the files. I asked the administrator to check the app with his Account and the EXE worked as I hoped. It accessed all images with extensions like JPEG, PNG, BMP, GIF etc. Thanks for showing that it was not a java issue but the OS security related issue.